# Keep SSH running on Windows 10 Bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having a problem keeping SSH running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux. It seems that if a shell is not open and running bash, all processes in the subsystem are killed. Is there a way to stop this?

I have tried to create a service using nssm but have not be able to get it working. Now I am attempting to start a shell and then just send it to the background but I haven't quite figured out how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to keep at least one bash console open in order for background tasks to keep running: As soon as you close your last open bash console, WSL tears-down all running processes.

And, yes, we're working on improving this scenario in the future ;)

### Update 2018-02-06

In recent Windows 10 Insider builds, we added the ability to [keep daemons and services running in the background](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/04/background-task-support-in-wsl/), even if you close all your Linux consoles!

One remaining limitation with this scenario is that you do have to manually start your services (e.g. `$ sudo service ssh start` in Ubuntu), though we are investigating how we might be able to allow you to configure which daemons/services auto-start when you login to your machine. Updates to follow.

Comment: Hey @rich-turner, Any improvement on this scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the ask … added an update to my answer :)

Comment: Could this hold potential for things like `cron`?

Comment: Kinda … though we're not (yet) auto-starting daemons on login, so not likely useful. Better option on Windows is to run a scheduled task

Answer (score 1):

To maintain WSL processes, I place this file in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\wsl.vbs

```
set ws=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
ws.run "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c 'sudo /etc/rc.local'",0
```

In /etc/rc.local I kick off some services and finally "sleep" to keep the whole thing running:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
/usr/sbin/cron
#block on this line to keep WSL running
sleep 365d
```

In /etc/sudoers.d I added a 'rc-local' file to allow the above commands without a sudo password prompt:

```
username * = (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/rc.local
username * = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/cron
username * = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/sshd
```

This worked well on 1607 but after the update to 1704 I can no longer connect to wsl via ssh.

Once you have cron running you can use 'sudo crontab -e -u username' to define cron jobs with @reboot to launch at login.

Answer (score 0):

Just read through this thread earlier today and used it to get sshd running without having a wsl console open.
I am on Windows 10 Version 1803 and using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS in WSL.
I needed to make a few changes to get it working. Many thanks to google search and communities like this.

I modified /etc/rc.local as such:

```
mkdir /var/run/sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd
#/usr/sbin/cron
```

I needed to add the directory for sshd or I would get an error "Missing privilege separation directory /var/run/sshd
I commented out cron because I was getting similar errors and haven't had the time or need yet to fix it.

I also changed the sudoers entries a little bit in order to get them to work:

```
username ALL = ....
```

Hope this is useful to someone.
John Butler